# comment on facebook post using graph api returns "Bad request"

Tags: windows-phone-7

i am trying to comment on a post using the graphi api, but i get a "Bad request" status in return.
i can successfully able to post to walls though.

the content of the response is "{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"(#100) Error finding the requested story"}}"

My request url is :https://graph.facebook.com/"postid"/comments?access_token="hereaccesstoken"&message=post%20a%20comment (removed postid & access_token).

i have these permissions: "publish_stream", "read_stream", "user_hometown", "user_checkins", "friends_checkins", "friends_photos", "user_activities", "friends_activities", "offline_access"

any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem when working on an Android app that interfaced with Facebook.  I was creating a wall post, then attempting to post a comment to it (needed to post text over 420 characters....so had to do it in a comment).

I was receiving the 'Error finding requested story' error when I wasn't requesting 'read_stream' permissions.  As soon as I requested 'read_stream' permissions when authorizing it worked.

Looks like you're already asking for those permissions - maybe double-check for a typo or something.  Also might be worth noting that I requested permissions in the array in order: read_stream first, then publish_stream.

Hope this helps.